# how to open cameras for face detection using opencv and flask

Tags: python, argparse, face-detection

I am working on one of my project but getting errors while I run the project.

[image: error]

Please need a help to solve this error

[image]

Comment: please change all screenshots to code blocks

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: error shows that you have to run it with argument - like `drowsiness_detection.py -p some_argument` and this argument will be used as `shape predictor`. OR if you don't need to load `dlib` then don't use `required=True`

Comment: how did you create this code if you don't know how it works?

Answer (score 0):

`Usage` and `Error` show that you have to run it with argument - like

```
drowsiness_detection.py -p path_to_dlib_facial_landmark_predictor
```

or

```
drowsiness_detection.py --shape-predictor path_to_dlib_facial_landmark_predictor
```

and you have to put correct path in place of `path_to_dlib_facial_landmark_predictor`.
I don't use `dlib` so I don't know what path it should be.

---

If you don't need `dlib's shape predictor` in your code then don't use `required=True` and it will not required it at start.

---

**EDIT:**

I found similar code in tutorial [Facial landmarks with dlib, OpenCV, and Python](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/03/facial-landmarks-dlib-opencv-python/)
and this tutorial shows how to run it

```
python facial_landmarks.py --shape-predictor shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat \
--image images/example_01.jpg
```

But first it needs to download [shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2](http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2) and uncompress it.